# How to change height of Annotation callout window Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

How to change size of Annotation Callout Window on Map in Swift. I tried to make a bigger CGSize on each of the component of the right and left view but without any success Height of the view in the end is still the same.

Here is my code:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    print("delegate called")

    if !(annotation is CustomPointAnnotation) {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "test"

    var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)
    if anView == nil {
        anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)


         selectedUstanova = (annotation as! CustomPointAnnotation).ustanova


        anView!.canShowCallout = true
    }
    else {
        anView!.annotation = annotation
    }

    //Set annotation-specific properties **AFTER**
    //the view is dequeued or created...

    let cpa = annotation as! CustomPointAnnotation
    anView!.image = UIImage(named:cpa.imageName)
    return anView
}
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView)
{
    let button : UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
    let image = UIImage(named: "telephone")
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    button.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true
    button.setBackgroundImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 200)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)


    let labelTitle :   UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20,0,150,50))
    labelTitle.text = selectedUstanova!.ime
    let labelSubTitle :   UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20,50,150,100))
    var ustanovaOpis = ""
    if selectedUstanova!.opis != nil{
        ustanovaOpis+=selectedUstanova!.opis!+"\n"
    }
    if selectedUstanova!.telefon != nil{
        ustanovaOpis+=selectedUstanova!.telefon!
    }
    labelSubTitle.text = ustanovaOpis
    let leftCAV : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,250,250));
    let leftCAV2: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,250,250));
    let imageB = UIImage(named: "bigbutton")
    let imageView : UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,300,300))
    imageView.image = imageB;
    leftCAV.addSubview(imageView)
    leftCAV.addSubview(labelTitle)
    leftCAV.addSubview(labelSubTitle)
    view.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftCAV;
    view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = leftCAV2;
}
```

Is there a chance of making View bigger i tried changing sizes of left and right callout accessory view but without success so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you were interested only in changing the height of the **annotation callout** here is the simple way. And I am just making the height to 200 units.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }
    let reuseID = "pin"
    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseID) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseID)
        pinView!.canShowCallout = true
        pinView!.animatesDrop = true
        pinView!.pinTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
     pinView!.detailCalloutAccessoryView = self.configureDetailView(pinView!)
    return pinView
}

func configureDetailView(annotationView: MKAnnotationView) -> UIView {
    let snapshotView = UIView()
    let views = ["snapshotView": snapshotView]
    snapshotView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[snapshotView(200)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
    //do your work 
    return snapshotView
}
```